# Upload Azure Pipelines File to Onedrive or similar

Tags: azure, file-upload, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, cloud-storage

In my pipeline on my Azure Devops project, I'm building my project and then zipping up the output into a file. However, at the moment, I have no way to access this archive.
I would like to upload it to a cloud storage service such as OneDrive, Google Drive, Dropbox or similar. But I haven't been able to find a simple way of doing this yet. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several approaches can be used. If only "access" to the zip is needed after a build has completed the [*Publish Build Artifact*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops) task is actually what you want.

This will publish specified files as artifacts within the completed pipeline job.
[image: Where to find the artifacts in the UI]
From within the detail view of the Build-Job you can then download and use whatever the pipeline produced.

It can be configured as a [build step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#steps), like this:

```yaml
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    pathToPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)' 
    artifactName: 'myCoolZip-$(Date:yyyyMMdd)'
```

Where the `pathToPublish` is the path to the artifact you want to publish.
Usually the compiled resources are copied to the `ArtifactStagingDirectory` and then the contents of that directory is published. This makes it easier if there are many steps that all contribute to the final artifact.

---

There are several community supported tasks that allow files to be uploaded to cloud-services:

- [rclone](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DifferentLife.rclone) (supports [a lot of providers](https://rclone.org/#providers), including OneDrive)
- [DropBox](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=louisgerard.zipandupload)
- [AWS3](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MFelling.AWSS3Upload)
- [SharePoint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=halliba.az-pipelines-2-sharepoint)
- [Cloudvault](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=odspefunfoundation.build-release-task)

However since Azure tends to update regularly these might not be so future-proof depending on the maintainer.

---

If you still want to upload your zip to the cloud where it is more accessible the easiest way would be to use the [FtpUpload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/ftp-upload?view=azure-devops) task.

```yaml
- task: FtpUpload@2
  inputs:
    credentialsOption: inputs
    serverUrl: ftp://someFtpServer.com
    username: yourUsername
    password: yourPassword
    rootDirectory: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)' 
    remoteDirectory: '/upload/$(Build.BuildId)/' 
    # Depending on your certificate you might need to set this to true
    # trustSSL: true
```

However don't place passwords and usernames directly into your YAML, [use secret variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#secret-variables) instead.

---

It is also possible to upload artifacts to Azure Storage by using the [AzureFileCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-file-copy?view=azure-devops) task

---

If you want more control add a script to your repository that does the uploading ([example script](https://gist.github.com/dindoliboon/3b16c4eb24df1fa4c56c)) and execute that as a [Command Line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) task.

Answer (score -6):

Use the Publish Artifact task to publish your build output. This will attach it to the build results. You will be able to download or consume the file in a downstream process such as a release definition.

Documentation is avalable [on learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops).

Comment: please can you include YAML code (to go into `azure-pipelines.yml`) in your answer for clarification.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=vsts

Comment: what about uploading to a cloud service? You just suggested how to consume the artifact.

Comment: Answer is not relevant at all